# How to open one JInternalFrame over another in JDesktopPane?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jinternalframe, miglayout

In my application, I am trying to open one `JInternalFrame` over another `JInternalFrame`  in single `JDesktopPane` that implements `MigLayout` but it is displaying second internal frame beside first internal frame. Where am I going wrong?

### Code

```
//MainClass.java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import java.awt.Color;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainClass extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    JDesktopPane desktopMain = new JDesktopPane();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainClass frame = new MainClass();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainClass() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 766);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnJinternalframe = new JMenu("Click Here");
        menuBar.add(mnJinternalframe);

        JMenuItem mntmOpenInternalFrame = new JMenuItem("Open Internal Frame");
        mntmOpenInternalFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JInternalFrame1 frame = new JInternalFrame1(desktopMain
                        .getPreferredSize());
                frame.setVisible(true);
                desktopMain.add(frame);
            }
        });
        mnJinternalframe.add(mntmOpenInternalFrame);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
                desktopMain.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.add(desktopMain, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        desktopMain.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[0px:1366px:1366px,grow,shrink 50,fill]", "[0px:766px:766px,grow,shrink 50,fill]"));
    }

}



//JInternalFrame1.java



import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JInternalFrame1 extends JInternalFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public JInternalFrame1(Dimension d) {
        setTitle("JInternalFrame1");
        setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 766);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(d);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][][][][][][][]", "[][][][][][]"));

        JButton btnClickMe = new JButton("Click Me");
        btnClickMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Container container = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JDesktopPane.class, (Component)e.getSource());

                if (container != null)
                {
                    JDesktopPane desktop = (JDesktopPane)container;
                    JInternalFrame2 frame = new JInternalFrame2();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    desktop.add( frame );
                } 
                
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnClickMe, "cell 7 5");

    }

}



//JInternalFrame2.java


import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JInternalFrame2 extends JInternalFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public JInternalFrame2() {
        setTitle("JInternalFrame2");
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 450);
        setSize(500,500);

    }

}
```

Comment: MigLayout hasn't something with rest of title, especially if setBounds for JInternalFrames is used

Comment: Why are using a layout manager on a `JDesktopPane`, it defeats the purpose of the component?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that uses only JSE classes and layouts.  Note the document is being reviewed and discussed on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214955/155831), contributions welcome.

Comment: Hello Mr.MadProgrammer, in my application i used mig layout because it helps to grow and shrink components in efficient way.Isn't there any way to achieve the purpose ?

Comment: i tried without using layout manager,it works fine on my system with current resolution but fails to display properly on changed resolution or changed monitor so i used layout managers.Please help me to get out of this successfully ,thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution,here is the code..

//MainClass.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainClass extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    static JDesktopPane desktopMain = new JDesktopPane();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainClass frame = new MainClass();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainClass() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 766);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnJinternalframe = new JMenu("Click Here");
        menuBar.add(mnJinternalframe);

        JMenuItem mntmOpenInternalFrame = new JMenuItem("Open Internal Frame");
        mntmOpenInternalFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JInternalFrame1 frame = new JInternalFrame1(desktopMain
                        .getPreferredSize());
                frame.setVisible(true);
                Dimension desktopSize = desktopMain.getSize();
                frame.setSize(desktopSize);
                frame.setPreferredSize(desktopSize);
                desktopMain.add(frame);
                dontmoveframe();
            }
        });
        mnJinternalframe.add(mntmOpenInternalFrame);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        desktopMain.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.add(desktopMain, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        desktopMain.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
    }

    public static void dontmoveframe() {
        try {
            JInternalFrame[] frames = desktopMain.getAllFrames();
            frames[0].setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Make first internal frame unmovable
        JInternalFrame[] frames = desktopMain.getAllFrames();
        JInternalFrame f = frames[0];
        BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI) f.getUI();

        Component north = ui.getNorthPane();
        MouseMotionListener[] actions = (MouseMotionListener[]) north
                .getListeners(MouseMotionListener.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
            north.removeMouseMotionListener(actions[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

//JInternalFrame1.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JInternalFrame1 extends JInternalFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public JInternalFrame1(Dimension d) {
        setTitle("JInternalFrame1");
        setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 766);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(d);
        setClosable(true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][][][][][][][]", "[][][][][][]"));

        JButton btnClickMe = new JButton("Click Me");
        btnClickMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Container container = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JDesktopPane.class, (Component)e.getSource());

                if (container != null)
                {
                    JDesktopPane desktopPane = getDesktopPane();
                    JInternalFrame2 f1 = new JInternalFrame2();
                    desktopPane.add(f1);//add f1 to desktop pane
                    f1.setVisible(true);
                    Dimension desktopSize = getDesktopPane().getSize();
                    f1.setSize(desktopSize);
                    f1.setPreferredSize(desktopSize);
                    MainClass.dontmoveframe();
                } 

            }
        });
        panel.add(btnClickMe, "cell 7 5");

    }

}
```

//JInternalFrame2.java

```
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JInternalFrame2 extends JInternalFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public JInternalFrame2() {
        setTitle("JInternalFrame2");
        setBounds(0, 0, 1366, 768);
        setClosable(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(
                new MigLayout("", "[][][][][][]", "[][][][][][]"));

        JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");
        btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JInternalFrame2.this.dispose();
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnBack, "cell 5 5");
        MainClass.dontmoveframe();
    }

}
```

Comment: If anyone find my answer useful please accept the answer,thank you.